# Using different Table for Authentication in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have created a different table for users, I created a Model and changed table name and Model name in auth.php file but still got this error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'grpchat_db.users' doesn't exist

any idea ?

Code for SuperAdmin Model. I wan to replace User model with this

```
namespace GroupChat;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class SuperAdmin extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
} ?>
```

auth.php

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Authentication Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
| This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
| attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'driver' => 'eloquent',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => GroupChat\SuperAdmin::class,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'super_admins',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reset Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You can also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'password' => [
    'email'  => 'emails.password',
    'table'  => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
],

];
```

Comment: `protected $table = "table_name";`?

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/12/changing-your-authentication-table

Comment: no @TimLewis , it doesn't work with this

Comment: @iCode4U I have all required columns and changed the table name as I said in question.

Comment: Right, and it sounds like you're still using `User` as your default model. Did you set Laravel to use this new `SuperAdmin` as your default `User` model for auth?

Comment: yes, I changed the value in config/auth.php file.  `'model' => GroupChat\SuperAdmin::class,`

Comment: Can you paste that as well? The only reason it would still be looking for a table called `users` is that you're using a model called `User` (which would look for a related table `users` unless you specified a different one called using the line from my first comment.) Also, note this line in `auth.php:` `'table' => 'users',`

Comment: @TimLewis. I added auth.php in question. Have a look

Comment: Hmm... Everything looks ok, although I haven't seen the `::class` part. Does it work if you just use `'model' => 'GroupChat\SuperAdmin'`? And if not, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Since you didn't answer the second half of my last comment, I'm assuming you're getting the same error. If this is the case, I have no idea what you're doing wrong...

Comment: It gives the same error

Comment: It looks like you've done everything right so far. In case it is a caching issue, try running `php artisan config:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @mallaudin When the error appeared? When you try to login or when you try to create new user? Check your controller and validation rules too.

Comment: @smartrahat this is not a validation error. I capture validation errors or more specifically Laravel captured. It was during creation of new user.

Comment: @mallaudin It's not a validation error but sometime validation might have `unique:users` or `exists:users,email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our conversation in comments I am posting my comments in answer.

Check your controller and validation rules too. It's not a validation error but sometime validation might have `unique:users` or `exists:users,email`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with validation rule, it was set to uniuqe:users. Replacing users with super_admins ( table name in this case ) solved the problem.

Comment: problem was identified by @smartrahat in comments